# Повторить post запрос

Tags: python

У меня есть вот такое тело post запроса

```
POST /api HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Host: test.com:2222
    Content-Length: 21
    Expect: 100
    Connection: close
    
    ididid=00001111222233
```

взял я его из браузера

Пытаюсь поторить запрос на python

```
import requests

url = "http://test.com:2222/api"
data = {'ididid': '00001111222233'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Host': 'test.com:2222', 'Content-Length': '21', 'Expect': '100', 'Connection': 'close'}
r = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
print(r.content)
```

При отправке запроса выдает ошибку 422 вместо ожидаемого ответа

Не могу понять, что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: А если не использовать `headers`? Просто `r = requests.post(url, json=data)`

Comment: сработало, но что не так с моей шапкой?

Comment: У вас просто стандартные заголовки, лучше отдавать их формирование модулю request

Comment: @SergBocharov `json=data`, когда в исходном запросе `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? В таком случае отправится `application/json`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Я об этом и написал, что заголовки будут стандартными и чтобы не делать ошибок лучше отдать их на откуп самому модулю requests

Comment: @SergBocharov Посмотрите, пожалуйста, нужный `Content-Type` в вопросе и посмотрите, [какой отправляется](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) при `requests.post(url, json=data)`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Перечитайте, пожалуйста, мой ответ. `aplication/json` - это не стандартный заголовок? Имело бы смысл возиться с заголовками, если бы была какая-то спецификация API, а так проще отдать их формирование модулю `requests`. Так понятнее изложил свою мысль?